# Avoid repetition of models in Django

Tags: python, django

I've a Django app that collects climatic data from different sources. Let's say for simplicity Temperature, Precipitation and Wind Speed, although in reality they are many more. I've a Django model for each of these magnitudes, representing a table that looks like (simplified version):

| datetime | location id | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/3/10 10:25 | 1 | 27 |
| 2022/3/10 10:35 | 1 |  |
| 2022/3/10 10:37 | 2 | 9999 |
| 2022/3/10 10:40 | 3 | 27 |

With hundreds of thousands of rows, collecting data for many years and many locations, and growing.

Now, this is the **raw** data: sometimes there is missing information (eg. row 2) and sometimes the data makes no sense (eg. row 3, with that 999).

For this data to be useful for any purpose, it needs to be clean up and validated, and hourly, daily and monthly averages (for each location) calculated. The **curated** data has exactly the same fields that the raw data. So, I have 4 sets of identical models (raw, hourly, daily and monthly) for each of the magnitudes of interest, as well as identical filters and views.

If this were just 3 magnitudes (Temperature, Precipitation and Wind Speed), it could be OK, but I have over 20 which results in A LOT of code repetition.

Do you have any suggestion of how I could improve the structure of my Django apps to avoid code repetition and make it easier to understand what is going on?

Comment: It will be helpful to show your current structure and the actual models. If they are in fact identical, you could just put them all in one model and add a `type` field so can filter for "wind", "precipitation", etc (this approach makes it easy to add new data types without changing the code base). If for some of them, behaviour/calculations are different, make an abstract base model and make them all inherit from it. Then put all the common fields/methods in the base model and the differing ones in the concrete models.

Comment: This is a good idea, similar to the one suggested by @zompa . My only concern is if there will be a performance issue for the end user, putting together the massive raw data tables with the much smaller and used regularly curated data ones. Specially if I not only combine the type of data (raw, daily, hourly, monthly) with the magnitude (Temperature, Precipitation, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, in my opinion you have 2 ways to improve it:

1. Use the same model, adding a field that classifies the recorded values (e.g. raw, clean, averaged, etc...)
2. Use model inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

In my experience I have often used more custom methods, such as the first, to have fewer constraints, but I have also used the second option successfully.